# Scrapy-splash response.css() can't get an element

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to scrape from a dynamic JS content website, I'm trying to get the breadcrumbs of the current page.

[image]

The breadcrumbs is consisted of 4 classes named : `'.breadcrumbs-link'`

[image]

To do so, I wrote this code, using scrapy-splash:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes4"

    start_urls = ["https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/browse/drinks/cordials-juices-iced-teas/iced-teas"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, endpoint='render.html',args= {'wait': 10})
    
    def parse(self, response):
        print ('Result:')
        print(len(response.css('.breadcrumbs-link').extract())) # OUTPUT: 0
        print(response.css('.breadcrumbs-link').extract()) # OUTPUT: []
```

What could be wrong about my approach ?

Comment: Did you check my answer below? If it didn't work for you, please let me know so I can review it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This website (`https://www.woolworths.com.au`) uses Angular. If you go at the [Splash FAQ page](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html), there is a section ["Website is not rendered correctly"](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#website-is-not-rendered-correctly) where we can see:

> non-working localStorage in Private Mode. This is a common issue e.g.
>   for websites based on AngularJS. If rendering doesn’t work, try
>   disabling Private mode (see [How do I disable Private mode?](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#disable-private-mode)).

And at the link we can see:

> [**How do I disable Private mode?**](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-disable-private-mode)
>
> With Splash>=2.0, you can disable Private mode (which is “on” by
>   default). There are two ways to go about it:
>
> at startup, with the `--disable-private-mode` argument, e.g., if
>   you’re using Docker:
>
> ```
> $ sudo docker run -it -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash --disable-private-mode
> ```
>
> at runtime when using the `/execute` endpoint and setting
>   [splash.private_mode_enabled](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-private-mode-enabled) attribute to `false`

The easy way is to disable private mode by using `--disable-private-mode`, but if you don't want to do that, then you can pass a Lua script that temporarily disables private mode for your spider and then enables it again when it's finished:

```python
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

LUA_SCRIPT = """
function main(splash)
    splash.private_mode_enabled = false
    splash:go(splash.args.url)
    splash:wait(2)
    html = splash:html()
    splash.private_mode_enabled = true
    return html
end
"""

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes4"

    start_urls = ["https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/browse/drinks/cordials-juices-iced-teas/iced-teas"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url,
                                callback=self.parse,
                                endpoint='execute',
                                args={
                                    'wait': 1,
                                    "lua_source":LUA_SCRIPT})

    def parse(self, response):
        print ('Result:')
        print(".breadcrumbs-link len = %d" % (len(response.css('.breadcrumbs-link').extract()))) # OUTPUT: 4
        print(".breadcrumbs-link = %s" % (response.css('.breadcrumbs-link').extract())) # OUTPUT: [...HTML ELEMENTS...]
```

It worked for me by disabling private mode with result:

```sh
Result:
.breadcrumbs-link len = 4
.breadcrumbs-link = ['<li class="breadcrumbs-link" ng-repeat="link ....
```

Comment: Thank you sir, your answer has solved the problem :)